# Java try-finally construction

Tags: java, exception

Could someone explain me some situation (example) when we can use this construction?

```
try{

        //dangerous code here
    } finally {

        //always called    
    }
```

I really understand how it works but newer use in real situation.

Comment: Finally blocks are not *always* called (think hitting the reset button while the code is running). You should not place critical business logic code in finally blocks for this reason. Closing streams and files is fine though

Comment: `// don't write dangerous code anywhere`

Comment: Thanks for all for answers)) Very good!

Comment: Is this [homework]? If so, please tag as such.

Comment: What do you mean [homework] ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    isWorking = true
    //doStuff that might or might not succeed
    } finally {
    isWorking = false;
    }
```

another example:

```
public void actionPressed()
  {
    if( isLoading )
      return;
    try {
    isLoading= true;
    doTheLoad);
    } finally {
    isLoading = false;
    }    
  }
```

Comment: I think it will be best answer for my question, because in another variants you will be catch exceptions and something do with them (for good coding). But in this variant we have isWorking = true field that can have any value at the end of try. But anyway we want that this field was false so we need this construction.
@Peter could you explain more realistic code (for example some method) that use this construction
Thanks)

Comment: I use this construction typicaly in listeners. User clicks on a refresh button, you start refreshing, while refreshing you dont want the refresh to happen again. But when the loading is done you want to allow it again
 public void actionPressed()
  {
    if( isLoading )
      return;
    try {
    isLoading= true;
    doTheLoad);
    } finally {
    isLoading = false;
    }    
  }

Comment: So in general meaning we can say that we can use this construction working with a flag?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any time you have something like a [`Closeable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), where you need to explicitly call `close()` to release the underlying resource, you want to put that call in a `finally` block, like:

```
FileReader f = whatever();
try {
    // do some stuff with f
    return;
}
finally {
    f.close();
}
```

Even if no exception is thrown, and the `return` inside the `try` block is run, the resource will still be closed correctly.

Comment: Although in Java 7 you would now use a try-with-resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/try-with-resources

Answer (score 2):

Some of the common scenarios:

1. Prevent resource leak:
   Close IO streams and DB connections
2. Message logging

Answer (score 2):

You might use it close database connections or any other resource - a file, hardware port, etc.

```
try{
     // Do something I care about
} finally {
    // Make sure we clean up, regardless of success or failure   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(...);
try {
    / * use in here */
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Basically, no matter what happens, `in` will always be closed. Without this, `in` could stay open until the garbage collector collects it (could be a **long** time). This is a problem because:

- There is a limit on the number of files / network connections you can have open at once
- Open network connections will continue to tie up resources on the remote end too (DB connections are a good example)
- Closing an input stream also flushes it generally (flushing writes anything in the inputstream's buffer)

Answer (score 2):

For instance when you read a file:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("...");
try {
    // do stuff
}
finally {
    is.close();
}
```

This way your file is always closed, even if there is an exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
openFile();
try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(someString);
    String sub = someString.substring(2);
    System.out.println(i+sub);
}
finally {
    closeFile();
}
```

as you can see, there might several Exceptions be thrown during a code passage and you possibly don't want to catch every of them.

also there could an Error be thrown, which you should not catch!

in any way you want to close your file, before the method ends, so you put that in the finally-block

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common pattern:

```
InputStream stream = // acquire stream...

try {
  // do stuff with stream that might throw...
}
finally {
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
}
```

Note, [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is a library from the Apache Commons project. You should always close the stream in a `finally`. `closeQuietly` eats any exceptions that might be thrown while trying to close the stream (which is OK because you can't do anything about it).

Comment: It is not always a good idea to close quietly. It can often be quite useful to, at the very least, log that an exception was thrown inside a finally block. This is really a developer convenience method.

Comment: To me its not convenience so much as eliminating a required and ugly nested try/catch block that there is nothing I can do about if an error occurs. If I log that `close()` failed, I still can't do anything about it... To me it is code pollution. And really, if `close()` fails, something horrible is going on and you will have plenty of indicators there is a problem ;-)

Comment: The reason I left the comment is because, as I learned the hard way, it may happen that there are not plenty of other indicators.  In this particular instance, I was troubleshooting a socket resource leak.  It turns out I was foolishly attempting to close a SocketChannel that was retrieved from a ServerSocket that was not opened via NIO.  Since the resultant SocketChannel was null, closeQuietly was swallowing a NPE which led me to believe that the code was working as I had expected it to.  I don't like looking at the nested try block either, but that is really the only problem it solves.

Comment: If you write code that throws a specific exception from Java, please for the love of other people that need to use your code, handle or at least log it...  Try finally is lazy.

Comment: `try-finally` is not lazy. You should only catch if you can handle it. If "handling it" means logging it and not re-throwing, great - however catch-log-rethrow up a chain of many classes, none of which can handle it, is an anti-pattern. As a general rule, exceptions should only be logged once.

Comment: By the way, I no longer use `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` from Apache Commons (which eats the exception without logging) and instead use `Closeables.closeQuietly()` from Guava (which eats the exception _and_ logs it).

Answer (score 2):

Especially we can use for data base connection close related  code in finally block. if program throws any exception in this case DB connection will release .

This is example in JDBC.same can be applicable in session.close() in Hibernate.
try{

```
    //dangerous code here 
} catch(Exception e){
  //Do some thing releted to your exception
} finally { 
  //close DB connection or close your hibernate session.

    //always called     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's say you open a connection to a database and make some queries. If a `SQLException` is raised by one of the queries, you're supposed to close the connection before doing something else. If no exception is raised, you're still supposed to close it.
So the `try {} catch () {}` is there to catch those `SQLExceptions` and do something about them, while the `finally {}` is there to close the connection in either case.
This would be a very common scenario, but the same is true with any resource that needs to be freed no matter what happens while using it.